# Regular Expression always false

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

So I am writing some javascript to check if a user inputs a gmail address.

At the moment I have the code thats below, but no matter what I do it is giving me `false`. even when the input has @gmail.com...I feel that the mistake is how I am grabbing the user input in a variable and then testing it with `test()`.

Javascript:

```
<script>
  function validationCheck() {
    var email = document.getElementById("inputEmail");
    var gmailPatt = /@gmail.com/i;
    var emailMatch = gmailPatt.test(email);

    if (emailMatch == false || emailMatch == true) {
      document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML =
        "<p>" + emailMatch + "</p>";
    } else {
    }
  }
</script>
```

html

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div>
      <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-1">Email:</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control col-sm-1"
        id="inputEmail"
        placeholder="username@gmail.com"
      />
      <p id="emailError"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="button" onclick="validationCheck()">Check</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the value of the input, `var emailMatch = gmailPatt.test(email.value);`

```js
function validationCheck() {
  var email = document.getElementById("inputEmail");
  var gmailPatt = /@gmail.com/i;
  var emailMatch = gmailPatt.test(email.value);

  if (emailMatch == false || emailMatch == true) {
    document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML =
      "<p>" + emailMatch + "</p>";
  } else {}
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div>
      <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-1">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-1" id="inputEmail" placeholder="username@gmail.com" />
      <p id="emailError"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="button" onclick="validationCheck()">Check</button>
</form>
```